# Is it possible to get a certain char of a string?

Tags: c++, string, oop

i have this code using class. how function `getDept()` can return first 3 char of string?

if i input `a1234567` i need function `getDept()` return `a12`

```
class ID
{
    string value;
    public:
        ID() { value=""; }
        void setID(string p) { value=p; }
        string getID(){return value;}
        string getDept() { ... }           //get first 3 char of string
};

int main()
{
    ID *emp = new ID;
    char st[10];
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        emp->setID(st);
        cout << emp->getID() << "have departement code : " << 
        emp->getDept() << " " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char st[10]; emp->setID(st);` is bad because `st` is not initialized.

Comment: Tip: Avoid `new`. Avoid C strings, use `std::string`. **Always initialize values before using them**.

Comment: Tip: For a getter, use a pattern like`const std::string& getX() { return x; } const`, with `const` references returned, and `const` set on the member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `string` here means [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), you can use the [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function.

```
string getDept() {
    return value.substr(0, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `using namespace std;` to your project then just

```
string getdept()
{
    return value.substr(0, 3);
}
```

Comment: [c++ - Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)